# How to solve equations with symsum inside

Tags: matlab

I need to solve a two-dimensional system of equations. I have a column vector, `SpreadCLPbp` where `N=length(SpreadCLPbp)` returns `500`.

I want to solve the following equations:

```
0 = sum_{i=1}^{N}{(-1/mu2 +exp(mu2*delta)/mu2)*(SpreadCLPbp(k)-(-mu1/mu2+(mu1/mu2+SpreadCLPbp(k))*exp(mu2*delta)))/(mu1*sigma/(2*mu2^2)-sigma^2/mu2*(mu1/mu2+SpreadCLPbp(k))*exp(mu2*delta)+sigma^2/mu2*(mu1/(2*mu2)+SpreadCLPbp(k))*exp(2*mu2*delta))}

0 = sum_{k=1}^{N}{(mu1/mu2+delta*exp(mu2*delta)*(mu1/mu2+SpreadCLPbp(k))-exp(mu2*delta)*mu1/mu2)*(SpreadCLPbp(k)-(-mu1/mu2+(mu1/mu2+SpreadCLPbp(k))*exp(mu2*delta)))/(mu1*sigma/(2*mu2^2)-sigma^2/mu2*(mu1/mu2+SpreadCLPbp(k))*exp(mu2*delta)+sigma^2/mu2*(mu1/(2*mu2)+SpreadCLPbp(k))*exp(2*mu2*delta))}
```

I tried to do the following

```
syms k mu1 mu2;

S1 = symsum((-1/mu2 +exp(mu2*delta)/mu2)*(SpreadCLPbp(k)-(-mu1/mu2+(mu1/mu2+SpreadCLPbp(k))*exp(mu2*delta)))/(mu1*sigma/(2*mu2^2)-sigma^2/mu2*(mu1/mu2+SpreadCLPbp(k))*exp(mu2*delta)+sigma^2/mu2*(mu1/(2*mu2)+SpreadCLPbp(k))*exp(2*mu2*delta)),1,N);

S2 = symsum((mu1/mu2+delta*exp(mu2*delta)*(mu1/mu2+SpreadCLPbp(k))-exp(mu2*delta)*mu1/mu2)*(SpreadCLPbp(k)-(-mu1/mu2+(mu1/mu2+SpreadCLPbp(k))*exp(mu2*delta)))/(mu1*sigma/(2*mu2^2)-sigma^2/mu2*(mu1/mu2+SpreadCLPbp(k))*exp(mu2*delta)+sigma^2/mu2*(mu1/(2*mu2)+SpreadCLPbp(k))*exp(2*mu2*delta)),1,N);

S = solve([S1 == 0, S2 == 0],[mu1, mu2])
```

But I get the following error:

> Error using sym/subsindex (line 732)
>       Invalid indexing or function definition. When defining a function, ensure that 
>   the arguments are symbolic variables and the body of the function is a SYM 
>   expression. When indexing, the input must be numeric, logical, or ':'.
>
> Error in analisisdatoscir (line 42)
>   S1 = symsum((-1/mu2+exp(mu2*delta)/mu2)*(SpreadCLPbp(k)-(-mu1/mu2+(mu1/mu2+SpreadCLPbp(k))*exp(mu2*delta)))/(mu1*sigma/(2*mu2^2)-sigma^2/mu2*(mu1/mu2+SpreadCLPbp(k))*exp(mu2*delta)+sigma^2/mu2*(mu1/(2*mu2)+SpreadCLPbp(k))*exp(2*mu2*delta)),1,N);

If someone could help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: Your code is not runnable. Multiple variables are undefined which make it impossible to replicate your issue.

Comment: `k` is an array index but you're also trying to use it as the `symsum` index. If `SpreadCLPbp` is just a floating point vector, I don't see why you can't rewrite to just use `sum` to create a single scalar.